# ExpandableListView and scrolling

Tags: android

I have an `ExpandableListView` and a `Button`. When I open some items in the list, I cannot access the button because the list has expanded.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/expEnt"
                />
    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:text="Plot"
            android:layout_below="@id/expEnt"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: I can access the button]
[image: I can't]

Is there some way to fix it?

Comment: layout_heightof the RelativeLayout should be match_parent. But i would recommend you to use LinearLayout vertical

Comment: steel the same problem

Comment: id you try with linerlayout ?

Comment: @VitaliyErmakov U need to fix that button at the end of layout right corner.. or end of ExpandableListView right corner..

Comment: Thanx... It's can solve my problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will might help you:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/expEnt"
                />
    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:text="Plot"           
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlot"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Plot" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnPlot"
        android:id="@+id/expEnt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If at any point in time when the child elements or the parent elements increase and the button still becomes invisible or out of reach, then add the following to the expandablelistview 
 
android:layout_marginBottom="75dp" // specify an approximate value

and use the code mentioned by @Basbous